# Twitter Bootstrap make select visible in input

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm busy with making an input field with a dropdown (~ Google Suggest).

With javascript I created a select and set it as child (inputElement.appendChild(select)).
The only problem is that I don't see the dropdown appearing  under the input field.

Can someone help me?
(I try to do this without jQuery, so pure javascript)

```
function toDrop(list, inputElement){
    var selectElement = document.createElement("select");
    for(var i = 0; i<list.length; i++){
        var option = document.createElement("option");
        var textNode = document.createTextNode(list[i]);
        option.appendChild(textNode);
        selectElement.add(option);
    }
    inputElement.appendChild(selectElement);
}
```

Within the HTML there is only an input tag:

```
<div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" autocomplete="off">
    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Find</button>
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you show a little more of your code?

Comment: when are you calling this function?

Comment: I'm calling this function after composing the list with predictions...